# Where did the term ノートパソコン come from?

Tags: etymology

When I first heard ノートパソコン I was a bit confused and thought they were referring to a PC brand or something.

Now that I think of it, it's a pretty appropriate term for a portable PC (laptop).

Was just curious where the term came from?

On that note (pun intended); laptop is starting to sound like a weird name, I don't think I have ever put a "laptop" on my lap... lol

Comment: You might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laptop ...

Comment: Thanx. Didn't see that, have never heard it called a notebook till I came to Japan though... I'm pretty sure in English most people would be confused which you're talking about.

Comment: Er, I'm a native English speaker from the US ...  another native speaker I'm talking to says its outdated. I did some work  in IT; I'd definitely heard the term before I came to Japan (though I agree "laptop" is the most common term by far).

Comment: @virmaior The point of me asking is not to say it should be called "laptop" (if you read my question I actually agree with it), this is purely for educational/curiosity purposes!

Comment: I'm merely responding to "I'm pretty sure in English most people would be confused which you're talking about." As a native speaker of English, that's not my impression.

Comment: So if you were back stateside (or w/e majority English speaking country you are from) and someone said "notebook", you would know they're talking about a "laptop"? There would be no confusion with a "paper book"?

Comment: With 100% certainty, yes I would know that's what they meant.

Comment: Wow. I guess cali is the hick side...

Answer (score 4):

The Japanese word for paper *notebook* is not ノートブック but [ノート](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88) (Hence [デスノート](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note), by the way). ノートブック was simply too long for Japanese people. Therefore, notebook PCs are naturally called ノートPC, ノートパソコン or simply ノート in Japanese. From my understanding, *laptop* is no longer common today also in English and it has been almost replaced by *notebook*.

We almost never use ノートブック to refer to paper notebooks, but when referring to notebook PCs, ノートブック(PC/パソコン) is common as well as ノート(PC/パソコン).

**EDIT:** Hmm, seeing the comments here, it appears that *notebook* (PC) is not yet widely used among native English speakers, although [manufactures stopped calling their products laptops long ago](http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Hardware_Software/laptop_notebook.asp). Here in Japan, ノートPC has already replaced ラップトップPC almost completely, even among ordinary people. Maybe that's because ノート is far easier for us to understand :)

Comment: I see. Unlike English, there wouldn't have been any confusion between which you were referring to. But have never heard anyone refer to them as notebooks till I came to Japan.

Comment: @keepkun Oh, really? Before posting this I checked some articles including [this](http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Hardware_Software/laptop_notebook.asp), and they basically say "laptop" is long-dead among PC manufacturers. Maybe ordinary English speakers are still mainly using laptop even after manufactures dropped this term and ordinary Japanese people have already accepted this term?

Comment: "Notebook" is also more common in Russian (and possibly other languages/regions), but I don't think it has a chance of replacing "laptop" in English any time soon. There was also a short period of "netbooks" in late 2000s and more recently "ultrabooks" but they both don't seem to be in much use anymore. Sorry for going off topic.

Comment: a netbook is different from a laptop/notebook... I'm not super familiar with ultrabook, but my initial sense (no dictionary etc) is that it would be a high performance laptop (notebook).

Comment: @naruto if "checked" means "I went to the U.S. or some other English speaking country and asked" then I guess I'm behind, else if "checked" means "I googled it" then I have my doubts.

Comment: @virmaior I always think of a netbook as a low performance laptop/high performance browser! haha

Comment: @keepkun I'm not following you. I distinguish netbook and ultrabook as having opposite meanings in contrast to laptops, but I confess to not really understanding what ultrabook means (the more I think about it, maybe ultrabook was a species of netbook?). I feel like that was a fad for a year that has now passed.

Comment: @keepkun I only googled. Articles I read (including Wikipedia) say something like "consumers use the two words interchangeably", "many people can't explain the difference", etc. And "XYZ-book" branding (netbook, MacBook, ...) has been around for more than a decade. So I never thought there were people who don't even understand what a notebook is in the US.

Comment: @naruto a "notebook" in English would be a paper book for writing in ("book" for "notes"), a non-English country may not confuse the 2 so can use it naturally but an English speaking country would definitely be confused by the 2!

Comment: @keepkun Do you mean, even with the context? For example, if I say "My desktop broke yesterday. I'll go to Best Buy and get a new notebook tomorrow," do you think this still is confusing or makes no sense in the US? What if I said "notebook PC" instead of only "notebook"?

Comment: I would suggest asking a question on "notebook" vs "laptop" usage on ELU or ELL, it's not really relevant to Japanese IMO.

Comment: I had no problem with ノート.  But the part that confused me was not making the connection between PC and パソコン, which I assume is from PERSOnal COMputer.  Right?